# XSLT - How to I correctly parse XHTML text

Tags: xml, xslt, xhtml

I am trying to parse some HTML (XHTML of course!) documents into XML so that I can later process these into other document formats.  I've been able to recursively parse through the node tree to extract node and attribute information but it doesn't handle the actual text very well.

Here is my example source:

```xml
<div>
    <p>
        <a href='http://google.com'>Text in A</a>
    </p>
    <p>Text in P</p>
    <p>How to <strong>emphasise</strong> text</p>
</div>
```

And I want it to produce something like this:

```xml
<div-tag>
    <id>first</id>
    <p-tag>
        <a-tag>
            <text>Text in A</text>
            <link>http://google.com</link>
        </a-tag>
    <p-tag>
    <p-tag>
        <text>Text in P</text>
    </p-tag>
    <p-tag>
        <text>How to</text>
    </p-tag>
    <strong-tag>
        <text>emphasise</text>
    </strong-tag>
    <p-tag>
        <text>text</text>
    </p-tag>
</div-tag>
```

I am using apply-templates to recursively go through the tree:

```xml
<xsl:template match="*">
<xsl:variable name="node-name" select="concat(local-name(),'-tag')"/>
<xsl:element name="{$node-name}">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="count(child::*) = 0">
            <xsl:if test="text()">
                <xsl:element name="text"><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></xsl:element>
                <xsl:if test="@href">
                    <xsl:element name="link"><xsl:value-of select="@href"/></xsl:element>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="child::*"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:element>
```

It ends up missing some of the text, where a node has text and also children, especially nested children ( in my example).  And if I set it to output text whenever it found any (and not just when there wasn't a child node), it  ends up showing the text of a child node as well.

Reading through the questions and answers here, I found a way to parse the text correctly...

```xml
<xsl:template match="div//text()">
    <xsl:variable name="node-name" select="concat(local-name(..),'-tag')"/>
    <xsl:element name="{$node-name}">
        <text">
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()" />
        </text>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

... but it doesn't pick nodes that don't have text, of course.  It misses the first p node as this doesn't have any text itself.  (I realise I will need to be careful what I do with paragraphs when I split them, as above, but that is tomorrow's problem!

I'm sure there must be a way to parse HTML into a more simple XML structure but I'm stumped at the moment.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell what exactly you want to achieve, based only on a small example and code that doesn't. Would the following work for you?

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}-tag">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@href">
    <link>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </link>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
    <text>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: First off - apologies for my poor examples.  I'll try to make them more complete next time.
Secondly - Yes!  That does work.  Thank you so much.
I'm just trying to get my head around it, but if I understand correctly, the apply-templates is set to parse through attributes and nodes, and then you have set up catches for href and text.  I think I can expand on this to complete it for all I need.
Thanks again, Michael.  It has put up my XSLT understanding by a notch.